# Supporting logical delete for an existing feed table

Tags: cassandra

I would like to implement logical delete for a news-feed record to support a later undo.
The system is in production, so any solution should support existing data.
Insert records to the feed is idempotent, thus inserting an already deleted record (has the same primary key) should not undelete it.
Any solution should support the queries to retrieve a page of existing or deleted records.

The feed table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_feed (
   tenant_id int,
   item_id int,
   created_at timestamp,
   feed_data text,
PRIMARY KEY (tenant_id, created_at, feed_id) )
WITH compression = { 'sstable_compression' : 'LZ4Compressor' }
AND CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created_at DESC);
```

There are two approaches I have thought of but both have serious disadvantages:
 1. Move deleted records to a different table. Queries are trivial and no migration is required, but idempotent inserts seems to be difficult (only read before insert?).
 2. Add is_deleted column. Create a secondary index for that column to support the queries. Idempotent inserts seems to be easier to support (lightweight transactions or an update trick).
The main disadvantage is that older records have null value, thus it requires data migration.

Is there a third more elegant approach? Do you support one of the above suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you maintain a separate table for deleted records, you can use CQL's `BATCH` construct to perform your "move" operation, but since the only record of deletion is in that table, you must check it first if you want the behavior you've described around not re-animating deleted records. Reading before writing is usually an anti-pattern, etc.

Using an `is_deleted` column *might* require some migration work, as you mention, but the potentially more serious problem you may have is that creating an index on a very low-cardinality column is usually extremely inefficient. With a `boolean` field, I think your index would contain only two rows. If you don't delete too frequently, that means your "false" row will be very wide and therefore [almost useless](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_when_use_index_c.html?scroll=concept_ds_sgh_yzz_zj__highCardCol).

If you avoid creating a secondary index for the `is_deleted` column and you allow both `null` and `false` to indicate active records, while only explicit `true` indicates deleted ones, you may not need to migrate anything. (Do you actually know which existing records to delete during migration?) You would then leave filtering deleted records to the client, who is probably already going to be in charge of some of your paging behavior. The drawback of this design is that you may have to ask for > N records to get N that aren't deleted!

I hope that helps and addresses the question as you've stated it. I would be curious to know why you would need to guard against already deleted records being brought back to life, but I can imagine a situation where you have multiple actors working on a particular feed (and the CAS problems that could arise).

On a somewhat unrelated note, you may want to consider using `timeuuid` instead of `timestamp` for your `created_at` field. CQL supports a `dateOf()` function to retrieve that date if that's a stumbling block. (It may also be impossible to get collisions within your `tenant_id` partitions, in which case you can safely ignore me.)

Comment: I need to guard against already deleted records being brought back to life, because the system is designed that a single record can be sent more than once (retries, migrations, self healing processes). In those cases it is expected that once a record is inserted, it will not be altered, unless a user deletes it.

Comment: About the `is_deleted`: assuming the partition key (tenant_id) is always specified in the query, the secondary index should be efficient also for low cardinality fields: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/26439396/3950710]