# Is Cassandra secondary index optimized if the partition key specified?

Tags: cassandra

For secondary index queries that the partition key is specified in the WHERE clause, does the secondary index lookup hits all cluster nodes, or just the node of the specified partition key?
If the latter is correct, then secondary index will be a good fit also for high cardinality fields (only for queries that satisfies the partition key).

EDIT: For example, for the following feed schema, query of a specific feed (feed_id specified) to retrieve existing or deleted feed items should be very efficient:

```
CREATE TABLE my_feed (
   feed_id int,
   item_id timeuuid,
   is_deleted boolean,
   data text,
   PRIMARY KEY (feed_id, item_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (item_id DESC);

CREATE INDEX my_feed_is_deleted_idx ON my_feed (is_deleted);

==> SELECT * FROM my_feed WHERE feed_id=1 AND is_deleted=false; --efficient?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you hit a partition key first, then it won't be a cluster wide operation. Only the target partition will be hit. If you have wide rows with many rows in a partition, a secondary index will be an efficient way to filter them down once a partition is hit.

Comment: not sure I understand "If you have wide rows with many rows in a partition". If I got it right, a secondary index should **always** be efficient if the partition key is specified in the query WHERE clause, whether the cardinality of the indexed field is high or low (because it won't be a cluster wide operation).  Is there any documentation supporting this case?

Comment: Secondary indexes aren't really for performance in Cassandra, rather to allow queries you wouldn't be able to do otherwise (without additional tables). For example, if you have clustering columns, you need to specify them in order. With a secondary index, after hitting a partition, you can efficiently filter on any column without specifying the clustering keys.

Comment: so even secondary index for a boolean field is efficient in this case (added an example to the question)?

Comment: Perf wise, it should be fine. Be aware though, that for very low cardinality (i.e. bool), the index table on each node (indexes are maintained locally) will have a row for true and a row for false. This may become an issue depending on row counts inside each partition. Also, if it's frequently updated / deleted, u may run into tombstone limits. Another approach is to simply query and filter client side. Have a read of this: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_when_use_index_c.html

Comment: @ashic, query only by secondary index is bad for high cardinality due to many node seeks to get little data and very low cardinal (bool) due to  lot of data - both slow and need pagination.

Specifying partition key in wide rows, you know where data is, no point of using index as its value points to partition key (not inside row) already available. It can simply "filter" wide row in place instead of returning all rows (IO) for partition key, otherwise sounds like "unoptimized" to me. Cardinality may not matter in wide rows as OP wants data that matches the constraint. Or, this a known bug?

Answer (score -1):

When and when not to use a secondary index and why is covered here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/cql/cql/cql_using/useWhenIndex.html