# How would one model somthing updateable, say like a “status” of a thing in Cassandra CQL3 and be able to query on this status?

Tags: java, cassandra, cql, cql3, nosql

This is a bit of a contrived example to illustrate my question, but let's say I have a Car entity which contains Lightbulb entities. A car has several lightbulbs, each of which could be "on", "off" or "broken".

Each type of lightbulb has a unique id. (left headlight = 100, right headlight = 101... that sort of thing)

The status of a lightbulb needs to be constantly updated.

What I'd like to do is query for a specific car for a set of lightbulbs with a specific status.

something like:
"*give me all the lightbulbs with* **status "on"** *for car "chevy" model "nova" vin "xyz-123""*.

```
create table lightbulbstatus (
   bulbid uuid,
   carmake text,
   carmodel text,
   carvin uuid,
   lastupdate timestamp,
   status int,  
                   /* row key *                /* col keys  */
   PRIMARY KEY( (carmake, carmodel, carvin), ?   ?    ?    ?)
);
```

I believe the row key should have the car coordinate in it, but beyond that, I'm a bit lost. I assume each time there is a status change to a bulb, we add a column. But I'm not sure what the keys should be in the column to make the query work.

I think in RDBMS-land, you could do a subselected or nested query to find bulbs with the status = on.

`select * from lightbulbstatus where status = 1 and lastupdate > (select lastupdate from lightbulbstatus where status != 1);`

No idea how you would do this in CQL3.  Obviously sub-selects are not allowed.

Comment: Why would you add a row for each status change? Do you need to track the changes, or is the current status enough? Of course, in your contrived example, it doesn't make much sense to track how often and when a direction light is turned on or off. In your actual use case, it may be necessary.

Comment: My intent was to add a new column with bulb id/status/time for each status change.  my partition key should be the car identifier.

Comment: Yes, that is what I surmised. I just wondered if that was necessary in your actual use case, or if it was maybe better to have a lightbulb entity with an on/off/broken status that could be changed. That is if you only need the current status and not the history of statuses.

Comment: @Handsomeguy Well, I don't really need a history of statuses.  I'm a bit new to nosql, and the impression I got was that it was better to write out a new record than to update some existing data.  Maybe not in this example, though.

Comment: Well, cassandra is optimized for writes, which means it is faster to write than to read or update. However, pushing data that is not necessary just because it is faster is not something I would recommend. Unless you need to update status VERY frequently, the read vs write is of no consequence. And that would also mean you got LOADS of obsolete data in your storage. I'll try an suggest a solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not have to maintain status history, I would suggest to have a single row for each bulb by the following primary key:

```
PRIMARY KEY( (carmake, carmodel, carvin), bulbid)
```

In order to query lightbulbs by status you need to create a secondary index:

```
CREATE INDEX lightbulb_by_status ON lightbulbstatus (status);

SELECT * FROM lightbulbstatus 
  WHERE status = 1 
    AND carmake = 'chevy' 
    AND carmodel = 'nova'
    AND carvin = cfe638e9-5cd9-43c2-b5f4-4cc9a0e6b0ff;
```

Although cardinality of the status is low, [your query includes the partition key and is highly efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26439396/3950710).
If the number of rows to be filtered is very small (like number of lightbulbs in a car), you may consider to filter lightbulbs by status in the application (and skip the secondary index).

If you should handle a case that an obsolete lightbulb status update might override a more recent status update (as your RDBMS query suggests), consider using [lightweight transactions](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_ltwt_transaction_c.html):

```
UPDATE lightbulbstatus set status = 0, lastupdate = '2014-11-08 23:50:30+0019'
  WHERE carmake = 'chevy' 
    AND carmodel = 'nova' 
    AND carvin = cfe638e9-5cd9-43c2-b5f4-4cc9a0e6b0ff 
    AND bulbid = 9124f318-8253-4d94-b865-3be07899c8ff 
  IF status = 1 AND lastupdate < '2014-11-08 23:50:30+0019';
```

Hope it helps.